# Using winsock on an AIX system - possible?

Tags: c++, winsock, native, aix

Is it possible to use winsock on an AIX system?

If not, is there any native support in C++ for unix based machines and e-mail support, without importing 3rd party libraries?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Winsock's analog in AIX is the use of the [BSD sockets API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets), which is what Winsock is based on.

There will be some differences, but if you have email code written in Winsock, you should be able to translate it to BSD API.

- Here's a tutorial/guide: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/
- Here's AIX 6.1's sockets guide: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.progcomm/doc/progcomc/ch9_sockets.htm#a3418a8c442endr